# very basic html/bootstrap/css

Tags: jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

Learning bootstrap at the moment, my html and css skills are basic, but learning lots with lynda.com and tutsplus.com

Basically, I got a bootstrap template from here:

http://ironsummitmedia.github.io/startbootstrap-modern-business/

The structure i want here is perfect for me to learn from - menubar at the top, slider just under,  then content under that.

What I want to acheive tho, is the menubar style here:

http://themeforest.net/item/equipo-responsive-wordpress-theme/full_screen_preview/8015431

Specifically, how the logo overlaps the slider.

Now I've "borrowed" the code for the menu bar and applied it to the bootstrap template, and come up with something like below:

http://tumolo.co.uk/fcslfn/

The logo, instead of overlapping the slider, it pushes it down. How can I make that logo overlap the slider please?

Thanks for all your help in advance.

Comment: "Borrowing" is ok until you receive a DMCA takedown request - https://www.astuteo.com/articles/stolen-website-design/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```css
.top {
 width: 1200px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  height: 100px;
  position: relative;
  z-index: 2;
  background-color: red;
}

.logo {
position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  background-color: black;
}

.slider {
position: relative;
  z-index: 1;
  width: 1200px;
  background-color: gray;
  height: 400px;
}
```

```html
<div class="top">
 <div class="logo"></div>
</div>
<div class="slider"></div>
```

Position logo absolute. First you need to add a class in "col-12" of the "div.top" and add position relative to it. I have added an example code how to do that.

Comment: worked a treat, locally - thank you.

Answer (score 0):

In your HTML, you can wrap the borrowed header in a div and inline-style it as such.

```
<div id="headerContainer" style="position:fixed; margin:0 auto; top:0; left:0; z-index:2000; width:100%;"></div>
```

Setting it as a fixed position will tell it to stay there and not move. Set your margins, then your location. Z-index makes it overlap anything under it's integer, and make sure to set the width to 100%.

Comment: worked a treat, locally - thank you.